Type on screen where I shouldn't using python
I'm writing a little snake game to my school programming project and I have a problem.
The problem is I'm controlling the snake on the windows terminal and after the snake dies the game takes to an other screen, the problem is the input I pressed to control the snake is there and on linux the problem it much worse. On linux when I press the keys to controll the snake it appears on the top left corner like i'm writing on notepad. I'm going to put here the GIFs to what I mean.
The GITHUB project: https://github.com/FLKS07/jogoDaCobra
The main.py file:
import os
import cobra
import terminal
import apples
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
import sounds
import keyboard_my as keyboard
import time

highscore_path = "../game_data/highscore.txt"
highScore = open(highscore_path).read()
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') 

try:
    speed = float(input("Qual é a velocidade de jogo? Maior número menor velocidade(1 É Padrão): "))
except:
    speed = 1
speed = speed/10
input("Pressione ENTER quando a janela de jogo está pronta!")



cobra = cobra.Cobra(1,1)
for x in range(0,3):
    cobra.addCaudas()

time.sleep(1)

heading = [0,0] #[X,Y]-

os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') # Limpa o ecrã

apples.generate_apple(cobra.caudas, cobra.x, cobra.y)



while True:
    terminal.handle_resize(cobra) 
    terminal.show_title(f"Points: {Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX}{cobra.getPoints()}{Style.RESET_ALL}, HighScore: {Fore.YELLOW}{highScore}{Style.RESET_ALL},")
    heading = keyboard.heading
    cobra.changePosition(heading[0],heading[1])    
    terminal.print_at(cobra.x, cobra.y, f"{Fore.WHITE}O{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    apples.print_apple()
    time.sleep(speed)
    if(cobra.checkDead() == True):
        break

keyboard.listener.stop()
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') 

file = open(highscore_path, 'w')
file.write(str(cobra.getPoints()))
file.close

sounds.play_sound_file("..\\sounds\\game_over.wav")
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear') 
print("GameOver, press ENTER to EXIT the game!") 
input()



The apples.py file:
import terminal
import random

from colorama import init as colorama_init
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style


apple_position_x = 0
apple_position_y = 0

def generate_apple(caudas, x, y):
    global apple_position_x
    global apple_position_y

    apple_position_y = random.randrange(1,terminal.console_height)
    apple_position_x = random.randrange(1,terminal.console_width)

    
    
    while(checkPos(caudas,x,y)):
        apple_position_y = random.randrange(1,terminal.console_height)
        apple_position_x = random.randrange(1,terminal.console_width)

    
def clear_apple():
    global apple_position_y
    global apple_position_x
    terminal.print_at(apple_position_x, apple_position_y, ' ')

        

def checkPos(caudas, x, y):
    for segment in caudas:
        if segment.x == apple_position_x and segment.y == apple_position_y:
            return True
        if x == apple_position_x and y == apple_position_y:
            return True
        return False
    

def print_apple():
    
    terminal.print_at(apple_position_x, apple_position_y, f"{Fore.RED}H{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    

The terminal.py file:
import sys
import shutil
import apples

console_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
console_height = shutil.get_terminal_size().lines

text_size = 0

def print_at(x, y, char):
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b7\x1b[%d;%df%s\x1b8" % (y, x, char))
    sys.stdout.flush()

def handle_resize(cobra):
    global console_width
    global console_height

    last_console_width = console_width
    last_console_height = console_height

    console_width = shutil.get_terminal_size().columns
    console_height = shutil.get_terminal_size().lines

    if(last_console_height != console_height or last_console_width != console_width):
        apples.clear_apple()
        apples.generate_apple(cobra.caudas, cobra.x, cobra.y)

def show_title(text):
    global text_size
    text_size = len(text)
    print_at(1,1, text)

The cobra.py file (snake):
import terminal
import apples
from colorama import init as colorama_init
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import Style
import sounds




class Cobra:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.caudas = []

        self.last_position_x = 0
        self.last_position_y = 0

        #print(f"Y: {terminal.console_height} X: {terminal.console_width}")

    def changePosition(self, x,y):
        self.last_position_x = self.x
        self.last_position_y = self.y
       
        self.x += x
        self.y += y
        

        # Wrap around if the position goes beyond the console width or height
        if self.x > terminal.console_width:
            self.x = 1  # Wrap to the start
        elif self.x <= 0:
            self.x = terminal.console_width

        if self.y > terminal.console_height:
            self.y = 1
        elif self.y <= 0:
            self.y = terminal.console_height
        
        for tail in self.caudas:
            tail.clear_self()

        for i in range(0, len(self.caudas)):
            if(i == 0):
                self.caudas[0].changePosition(self.last_position_x, self.last_position_y) 
            else:
                self.caudas[i].changePosition(self.caudas[i - 1].last_position_x, self.caudas[i - 1].last_position_y)


        # Show the tails on the screen
        for tail in self.caudas:
            tail.show_screen()

        if(apples.apple_position_x == self.x and apples.apple_position_y == self.y):
            sounds.play_sound_file("../sounds/pickup.wav")
            Cobra.addCaudas(self)
            apples.generate_apple(self.caudas, self.x, self.y)

        
        #print(f"New position: X = {self.x}, Y = {self.y}")

    def addCaudas(self):
        self.caudas.append(Cauda(self.last_position_x, self.last_position_y))
    
    def getPoints(self):
        return len(self.caudas)
    
    def checkDead(self):
        for x in range(len(self.caudas)):
            if(self.x == self.caudas[x].x and self.y == self.caudas[x].y):
                return True
        return False
    
    def checkCoordineIsOcupied(self,x,y):
        if(x == self.x and y == self.y):
            return True
        else:
            for x in range(len(self.caudas)):
                if(self.caudas[x].x == self.x and y == self.caudas[x].y):
                    return True
            return False

class Cauda:
    def changePosition(self, x, y):
        self.last_position_x = self.x
        self.last_position_y = self.y

        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.last_position_x = self.x
        self.last_position_y = self.y
    def clear_self(self):
        terminal.print_at(self.x, self.y, chr(32))
    def show_screen(self):
        terminal.print_at(self.x, self.y, f"{Fore.GREEN}A{Style.RESET_ALL}")

The keyboard_my.py file:
from pynput import keyboard as pkeyboard

heading = [0, 1]

def on_press(key):
    global heading
    
    try:
        if key.char == 'a':
            heading = [-1, 0]
        elif key.char == 'd':
            heading = [1, 0]
        elif key.char == 'w':
            heading = [0, -1]
        elif key.char == 's':
            heading = [0, 1]
    except AttributeError:
        # Handle special keys here if needed (e.g., arrows, etc.)
        pass

# Start the listener in the background
listener = pkeyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()

and sounds.py file:
from playsound import playsound
import threading



def play_sound_file(sound_file):
    threading.Thread(target=playsound, args=(sound_file,), daemon=True).start()

I tried to remove inputs on the code but to no sucess.
